# What do some Craft permissions mean?

Tags: permissions

I'm documenting Craft permissions for internal use but there are some permissions that I'm not clear on.

- "Access the site when the system is off" What system?
- "Publish live changes" How can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the site when the system is off means that a logged in user with that permission can view the website front end (I think - never actually used this). You can set the system status in Settings > General, or via the craft/config/general.php file using 'isSystemOn' => true/false.

If a user doesn't have "Publish live changes" it means that the user can create new entries, but they can't appear on the front end of the site because they can't set the entry status to be published (the green lightswitch button on all Entries). This means you can review their content as a more privelidged user before they get made public.